# Tool to monitor/log specific Windows messages

Tags: software-development, monitoring

I'm currently developing an application that uses private Windows messages to trigger (some) code execution (for programmers: defined as [WM_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + n).

I would like to track the order in which some of these are processed by the OS and handled in my app. I can not find sufficient facilities in my IDE to do so.

A free tool would be nice.

FWIW I Develop in Delphi XE2

Comment: Your requirement is pretty specific.  I'm not sure you'll find such a tool.  However, writing a windows hook to peek messages should not be that difficult or time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio ships with a program call spyxx.exe that does what you need I think.  You point it at your application and it shows you what messages it receives.  You can filter to just specific messages or ranges if you like.  It probably ships with the community editions of VS.

Comment: Thanks. The executable name is spyxx.exe, but MS calls it [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found out later, through [posting at StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915252/how-to-log-monitor-selected-wm-usern-windows-messages) that it **is** possible from within my program.

This solves my immediate problem, but I'm leaving the question (and this answer) up for others.